Understanding compressible Euler equations
I' successfully implemented a grid-based solver for incompressible euler flow which is pretty simple since the continuity equation reduces to the condition that the divergence of the vector field must be zero from which I can simply derive the poisson pressure equation.
For advection I use the semi-lagrangian approach allowing larger time-steps than specified by the CFL-condition.
The basic principle is: advect the velocity field -> calculate pressure -> add the negative pressure gradient to the velocity field -> repeat.
If I have an additional field like dye or temperature I can just advect it based on the velocity field and everything is fine.
But why is inviscid compressible flow so much harder? I understand that density is not a constant anymore and everything is coupled since gases can expand due to temperature flux which directly affects density since hotter areas are less dense and so on.
My basic idea was that I have several conserved fields like density field as it is, a density-temperature field (representing the evolution of $\rho T$) density-velocity fields and so on.
I then tried to somehow introduce semi-lagrangian approach (I know it's not conservative, but I jsut wanted a proof of concept, and since my simulation time is very short I dont think the conservation issues will be severe) but since there is no direct advection operator anymore (i.e. $(u\cdot\nabla)\theta$) but rather $\nabla(\rho\theta\cdot u)$ I applied the product rule to obtain the known advection operator:
$$\nabla(\rho\theta\cdot u) = \rho\theta\cdot\nabla u + (u\cdot\nabla)\rho\theta.$$
As one can see applying the product rule reveals that there is not only advection going on but the divergence of the vector field plays a crucial role too. For incompressible flow this is omitted since divergence is zero!
My idea therefore was to first advect an arbitrary conserved field $\rho\theta$ (be it density, density-u, density-v, density-temperature) with semi-lagrangian then subtract the divergence of the vector-field.
After doing so for density, temperature and velocity I then calculate the pressure based on ideal gas law: $p=\rho\cdot T\cdot R$ whereas R is a specific gas constant.
It doesn't look as promising as my incompressible solver.
Is my approach wrong? Must I not apply the product rule but somehow figure out how to calculate $\nabla (\rho\theta\cdot u)$ in a more stable fashion?

To answer your question, it might help to provide some details about your numerical method. From a physical point of view, the compressible Euler equations are of hyperbolic nature and allow for unsteady solutions, such as shock-waves, which should be handled by the numerics.

@ConvexHull I dont want to deal with very high mach numbers, my problem setting is rather simple: empty metal container gets heated up by high temperature natural gas which is ejected from a pipe at moderate velocities so I dont expect shock-waves. My primary goal is to get convective currents due to temperature differences. I use pretty basic stuff: Discrete laplacian (left + right + down + up - 4*current divided by $dx^2$), basic finite difference approach to calculate divergence and upwind scheme to calculate pressure gradient.

The Euler equations require an equation of state (relating pressure to total energy and density) and should have 2+$d$ equations (where $d$ is the number of dimensions you're working with). Your assertions about whatever $\rho\theta$ is supposed to be don't line up with the typical Euler equations as commonly expressed in the formulation I think everyone else would be familiar with. Can you write the complete set of PDEs you are intending to solve?

@KyleKanos I hope I dont emberass myself but I didn't try to solve the complete energy equation (which is very confusing) but instead focused on the evolution of the temperature field. So I try to solve
1.) continuity equation: $\frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{t}} + \nabla(\rho u) = 0$
2.) momentum equation: $\frac{\partial{\rho U}}{\partial{t}} + \nabla(\rho u \otimes u) = 0$ on which I applied the product rule to get $u\cdot(u\cdot\nabla\rho) + (u\cdot\nabla)\rho u + \rho u(\nabla u)$
3.) Temperature equation: $\frac{\partial{\rho T}}{\partial{t}} +\nabla(\rho T u) = \alpha\nabla^{2}T$

If you're working with the Euler equations, then you already have the set of 2+$d$ equations to solve:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[\begin{array}{c}\rho \\ \rho\mathbf{v} \\ E\end{array}\right]+\nabla\cdot\left[\begin{array}{c}\rho\mathbf{v} \\ \rho \mathbf{v}\otimes\mathbf{v}+p\mathbf{I} \\ (E+p)\mathbf{v}\end{array}\right]=0\tag{1}$$
where $E=\rho e+\rho v^2/2$ is the total energy and $\mathbf{I}$ the identity matrix; all other symbols take their normal meaning. The only thing missing is a closure condition that relates the pressure to the remaining state variables (density, velocity and/or energy). Often one uses the ideal equation of state in which $p=\rho e(\gamma-1)$ where $\gamma$ is the adiabatic index. Using this equation of state, your total energy relation becomes,
$$E=\rho e+\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2\equiv\frac{p}{\gamma-1}+\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2$$
which eliminates the (internal) energy density, $e$, in favor of the pressure.
You also have the ideal gas law that says $p\propto\rho T$, so there really isn't a 'temperature advection' type equation, the temperature is determined by the pressure and density in each computational grid cell. For other gas laws, it may require a root solver to determine the temperature if it's not an easily invertible function.
So I think overall that you need to start with Equation (1), express each as the semi-Lagrangian formulation and then add those to your numerical solver. Since temperature is determinable from the pressure and density, you can compute that directly whenever is needed (e.g., in outputs).

Expressed in the comments,

So let's take $∇(ρv⨂v)$ for example. How would I even solve this numerically? Just do explicit euler + central differences to obtain the divergence but with dt smaller than what CFL dictates? Or am I allowed to apply product rule to obtain advection of velocity, divergence of velocity and advection of density to solve them seperately?

Consider for a moment ignoring the density, the divergence of the dyad product of two vectors yields (cf. this Math.SE post),
$$\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{a}\otimes\mathbf{b})=(\nabla\cdot \mathbf{a})\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{b}$$
Now if we let $\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{b}=\rho\mathbf{v}$, we have,
$$\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{v}\otimes\rho\mathbf{v})=(\nabla\cdot \mathbf{v})(\rho\mathbf{v})+\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla(\rho\mathbf{v})$$
Which suggests that if you treat the momentum density as a single variable (rather than 2 separate variables), you can treat it exactly the same as the other state variables (density, total energy) when deriving your algorithm. It's just that under the assumption of compressibility, the condition $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}=0$ no longer holds & you cannot remove those terms in your equations.

As an aside, hours later, it has been a long time since I looked at the semi-Lagrangian method, but I do believe that I've seen it defined in terms of the primitive variables (density, velocity, pressure) instead of the conservative ones (density, momentum density & energy density). If converting Eq (1) doesn't lend itself to something useful, try it with the primitives instead.

I dont want to be annoying, but my very problem is that I am not sure whether or not applying the product rule to somehow obtain the advectional term is valid. So let's take $\nabla{(\rho v \bigotimes v)}$ for example. How would I even solve this numerically? Just do explicit euler + central differences to obtain the divergence but with dt smaller than what CFL dictates? Or am I allowed to apply product rule to obtain advection of velocity, divergence of velocity and advection of density to solve them seperately?

See edits @Statistik

Woah, so the formula still consists of advection of my conserved field rho-v (and not v anymore) + the divergence of rho-v which would be zero if density was assumed constant (=> incompressibility).. fascinating.

@Statistik Correct, treating it as momentum density does keep the mathematics (and often the numerics!) a bit cleaner. If you feel this post has helped, please upvote and/or accept the answer.

My last question then is whether or not its necessary to calculate the energy or whether it is enough to calculate the temperature field (advection + diffusion) to then obtain the pressure. What do you think? Best regards

I have only ever seen hydrodynamic codes written using either pressure, total energy or entropy as the closure PDE (all three forms written here) and temperature defined as $T\sim p/\rho$. I suppose, though, that if you used this definition of the temperature, you could re-write the pressure equation in terms of the temperature, but there might be more work involved in the change of variables.

Thanks for replying. As far as I see the pressure equation (which is obtained from the energy equation I expect) is once again nothing but advection of pressure by the velocity field plus the divergence of the velocity field scaled by the pressure and some constant. So, this makes sense.. everything is nicely coupled. But how would I "inject" quantities into the system? Suppose I want to simulate a wind canal where a certain horizontal velocity is injected from the right side of the domain with a specific temperature. Could I convert that to pressure and add it to the pressure field?

That sounds like Boundary Conditions, which you would apply after each time step increment. But yes, you could convert the temperature to a pressure & apply that to the right edge boundary.

Thanks, that clearifies most things!
